# Ignoring "ignore" hints

Tags: reactjs, code-coverage, jestjs, istanbul

I am trying to provide ignore hints to Jest/Istanbul, but they are being ignored completely - coverage is unchanged. For example:

```
/* istanbul ignore if */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const fromStateStr = JSON.stringify(fromState);
    const toStateStr = JSON.stringify(toState);
    console.log(
        `RouterStore.transition(${fromStateStr}, ${toStateStr})`
    );
}
```

I have also tried `/* istanbul ignore next */` on individual lines, but there's no change. Am I missing some setting? Here's my Jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "./test/test-shim.ts",
    "./test/test-setup.ts"
  ],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/test/"
  ],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 90,
      "functions": 95,
      "lines": 95,
      "statements": 95
    }
  },
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "mapCoverage": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this was that the TypeScript compiler was removing all comments, including the Istanbul hints. Therefore tests were ignoring all hints. Had to add `"removeComments": false` to tsconfig.json to make this work.

P.S. Thanks to Lucian Lature for pointing this out.

Comment: Saved me a headache. this doesnt cause the removecomments to be removed for builds does it?